# Complements of bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What constraint must be placed on a bipartite graph G to guarantee that G's complement will also be bipartite?

Does it have to have at most 2 vertices on each side and be complete? Thanks

Comment: What happen in the complement of $G$ if $G$ has a part of size greater or equal to 3?

Comment: @hbm Isn't the complement not bipartite in that case? Since you can't partition the vertices into two sets such that the vertices in one set are joined with an edge to the vertices in the other set

Comment: Yes. That means that if one of the parts has size greater or equal to $3$ the complement cannot be bipartite.

Answer (score 1):

1) As hbm said, each part of $G$ has to contain less than $3$ vertices.
2) Also in the case when the total number of vertices is $4$, each vertex of $G$ has to be incident to at least one edge. If some vertex is not incident to any edge (unconnected graph) then $G$'s complement has at least one $3$-cycle and it's not a bipartite.

The cases of graph with $1, 2$, or $3$ vertices in total are trivial.